# I have a problem in installing flutter, I really need to solve it

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

This is my issue in installing flutter do any one know how to solve it ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1) Open android studio go to sdk manager select Android SDK Command-line tools and click apply wait for it to to install [image]

Step 2) After following step 1 open PowerShell and write flutter doctor --android-licenses

and accept all by pressing y repeatedly after accepting all run flutter doctor again all it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Run the commands mentioned in the console.

`sdkmanager` is in `\tools\bin` in Android SDK folder.

Run

```
ANDROID_SDK_PATH\tools\bin\sdkmanager.bat  --install "cmdline-tools;latest"
```

Then, Run

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```