# How to install flutter without android studio?

Tags: android, linux, flutter, dart

I want to install flutter without android studio in linu.When i type flutter command it shows

```
Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ cmdline-tools component is missing
  Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
  See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
```

Please tell me what is the soltuion.

Comment: You can use flutter without Android Studio, You do only need `Android SDK`

Comment: check out my this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/69411806/13823875

Comment: @WaliKhan How is that an answer to the question that ends in "without android studio"?

Comment: @nvoigt my answer solves the problem of cmdline-tools component is missing thats why i replied in comment and not gave him answer

Answer (score 0):

Without Android studio. It is not possible to setup flutter. Android Studio is necessary to install but Visual Studio Code is an option. For more read..

[https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#:~:text=by%20these%20services.-,Android%20setup,-Note%3A%20Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows#:%7E:text=by%20these%20services.-,Android%20setup,-Note%3A%20Flutter)